# Apple Preview and Chrome Color Profile Accuracy?

Tags: macos, color-profiles, preview.app

I have been having some issues with understanding how Apple's preview deals with Color profiles. I have noticed that when viewing a standard sRGB image on my Dell u2711 or MacBook Display that the same image appears to be more saturated and vibrant in Chrome than in Preview.

I realize I am using wide gamuts and also that Chrome does not support any ICC profiles, but how can I ensure my colors are being reproduced accurately for the web, including both lower end monitors and wide gamut displays?

Here is an image showing what I am talking about:

[image: Chrome logo example]

The image to the left is in Chrome and the image to the right is Preview (Mountain Lion).
If you have a wide gamut display, the logo on the left will be much more vibrant, but the file is the same!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, but according to different websites Chrome makes colors too saturated on wide gamut displays. As a workaround, you could open it with `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-monitor-profile`.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143#c158

> --enable-monitor-profile works by mapping everything to sRGB and then applying the sRGB->monitor profile transformation. This prevents CSS colors and untagged images from becoming oversaturated on a wide gamut monitor but does not preserve the large gamut of color spaces like Pro Photo RGB and Adobe RGB 1998.
>
> A complete color management solution is pending http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37028

You could also [reduce the gamut of the display](http://cameratico.com/guides/web-browser-color-management-guide/).

> Besides asking browser developers to fully support color management on their software, there’s a workaround we can use on most wide gamut LCDs to make web colors look right: reduce their gamut temporarily. Most of those displays have a “color mode” or "color presets" menu on their controls that allows you to apply an sRGB simulation to the monitor.
>
> The workaround would be to switch the display to sRGB and produce a color profile specific for that mode. When browsing the web, you’d select the sRGB profile and switch the display to sRGB by using its on-screen controls.
>
> Depending on how you use your computer it could work for you, but clearly it doesn’t work for me since I browse the web while I work on Photoshop and other color managed programs, where a large gamut would be beneficial.

Chrome doesn't support ICC profiles either. Images that aren't saved as sRGB aren't displayed correctly:

[image]